# Как вывести Queryset?

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

Похоже я сильно туплю, но есть две модели: `Product` и `Category` (реализация супер-банальная).

Во `view` я отправляю в шаблон экземпляр `Product` и в шаблоне хочу вывести в цикле определенный `Product` и его `Category`.

Как вывести Category?

Он мне дает только

```
queryset(Queryset[<Category: Десерт>, <Category: Горячее>]).
```

А как это дело распаковать? Без вложенных циклов только пж...

```
class Prodduct(models.Model):
    title = models.Charfield()
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category', 
related_name='quotes_category')


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что запросы в `Django` - ленивые. Это значит то, что фреймворк будет стараться оттягивать момент запроса в БД до последнего, пока не требуется что-то вывести на печать, а пока это возможно, как в вашем случае, возвращать вместо самих объектов - `QuerySet`.

По сути, `QuerySet` - это просто набор запросов к базе данных **(но не результат!)**, которые сохранены в конкретном объекте, и которые можно в дальнейшем выполнить.

Допустим, у вас есть модель `Product`, тогда запрос

```
all_products = Product.objects.all()
```

вернет `QuerySet`, поскольку в данный момент никакого вывода не требуется.

Есть несколько случаев, когда QuerySet все-таки выполняется и происходит отправка запроса в БД, приведу несколько самых частых:

1. Итерация

   `for product in all_products: ...`
2. Получение одной записи

   `product = Products.objects.get(id=1)`
3. Преобразование в `list`

   `products = list(Products.objects.all())`

Остальные примеры можно прочитать в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

Comment: Я добавил код. Мне нужно, чтобы в шаблоне я мог выводить Product и рядом его Category. Проблема в том, что я из view отправляю лишь экземпляр Product(x = Product.objects.all()), а потом пытаюсь вывести все продукты и категорию каждого.
for i in x:
    {{ i }} - {{ i.quotes_category }}
Выводит: "Яблоки - (Queryset[<Category: Фрукты>).
Нужно: "Яблоки - Фрукты"

Comment: @hg так а как вы хотите? у вас по факту по этому полю стоит `QuerySet`, он его и показывает. вы можете написать `i.quotes_category[0]` и отобразятся Фрукты, но если будет более чем 1 объект, то остальные вы просто потеряете. я бы предложил во `view` разобраться со всеми этими связями и в `context` уже передавать словарь, где ключ - это ваше `i`, а значение - список! (который вы создадите), со всеми объектами из `QuerySet`

Comment: Окей, понял. Просто думал, что подобным образом можно выводить и категории тоже. Поэтому пытался разобраться. Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: @hg в принципе можно, но тогда придется использовать вложенный цикл, который вы хотели избежать)